# Data Structures and Algorithmn in C++ 2nd Ed - Goodrich . Page 295 question on vector-based structure binary tree worst case for space 2^n - 1

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, tree, binary-tree, big-o

Let me explain as best as i can. This is about binary tree using vector.
According to author, the implementation is as follows:

> A simple structure for representing a binary tree T is based on a way of numbering
> the nodes of T. For every node v of T, let f(v) be the integer defined as follows:
> • If v is the root of T, then f(v) = 1
> • If v is the left child of node u, then f(v) = 2 f(u)
> • If v is the right child of node u, then f(v) = 2 f(u)+ 1
> The numbering function f is known as a level numbering of the nodes in a binary
> tree T, because it numbers the nodes on each level of T in increasing order from
> left to right, although it may skip some numbers (see figures below).

[image]

> Let n be the number of nodes of T, and let fM be the maximum value of f(v)
> over all the nodes of T. The vector S has size N = fM + 1, since the element of S at
> index 0 is not associated with any node of T. Also, S will have, in general, a number
> of empty elements that do not refer to existing nodes of T. For a tree of height h,
> N = O(2^h). In the worst case, this can be as high as 2^n − 1.

Question:

1. The last statement worst case 2^n-1 does not seem right. Here n=number of nodes. I think he meant 2^h-1 instead of 2^n-1. Using figure a) as an example, this would mean 2^n -1 means 2^15-1 = 32768-1 = 32767. Does not make sense.

Any insight is appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The worst case is when the tree is degenerated to a chain from the root, where each node has two children, but at least one of which is always a leaf. When this chain has *n* nodes, then the height of the tree is *n/2*. The vector must span all the levels and allocate room for full levels, even though there is in this degenerate tree only one node per level. The size S of the vector will still be O(2<sup>*h*</sup>), but now that in this degenerate case *h* is O(*n/2*) = O(*n*), this makes it O(2<sup>*n*</sup>) in the worst case.

The formula 2<sup>n-1</sup> seems to suggest the author does not have a *proper* binary tree in mind, and then the above reasoning should be done with a degenerate tree that consists of a single chain where every node has at the most one child.

### Example of worst case

Here is an example tree (not a proper tree, but the principle for proper trees is similar):

```
           1
          /
         2
          \
           5
            \
             11
```

So *n* = 4, and *h* = 3.

The vector however needs to store all the slots where nodes *could have been*, so something like this:

```
                     _____ 1 _____
                    /             \
                 __2__          __   __     
                /     \        /       \
                      _5_   
             /   \   /   \   /  \     /   \
                         11
```

...so the vector has a size of 1+2+4+8 = 15. (Even 16 when we account for the unused slot 0 in the vector)

This illustrates that the size S of the vector is always O(2<sup>h</sup>). In this worst case (worst with respect to *n*, not with respect to *h*), S is O(2<sup>n</sup>).

### Example n=6

When n=6, we could have this as a best case:

```
         1
       /   \
      2     3
     / \     \
    4   5     7
```

This tree can be represented by a vector of size 8, where the entries at index 0 and index 6 are filled with nulls (unused).

However, for n=6 we could have a worst case ("worst" for the impact on the vector size) when the tree is very unbalanced:

```
           1
            \
             2
              \
               3
                \
                 4
                  \
                   5
                    \
                     7
```

Now the tree's height is 5 instead of 2, and the vector needs to put that node 7 in the slot at index 63... S is 64. Remember that the vector spans each *complete* binary level, which doubles in size at each next level.

So when *n* is 6, S can be 8, 16, 32, or 64. It depends on the shape of the tree. In each case we have that S=O(2<sup>h</sup>). But when we express S in terms of *n*, then there is variation, and the best case is that S=O(*n*), while the worst case is S=O(2<sup>*n*</sup>).

Comment: The author is strictly talking about proper binary tree .. meaning a node will have 0 child or 2 children.

Comment: OK, I didn't see that in the quote, but that doesn't affect big O. I updated the text. But their formula suggests that in that phrase the author did not have a proper binary tree in mind. I don't have the book, so I can't check.

Comment: Your statement  O(n/2) = O(n) this makes it O(2^n). I understand O(n/2) = O(n). But how did from O(n) you arrive at O(2^n)?

Comment: The O(n) is about what *h* is in that worst case, while O(2*n) is about S (not *h*). See addition to answer.

Comment: Thx for your diagram but let's go back to figure a). h=4. S=vector length - meaning vector size() i.e. number of elements. What's S for figure a)? There are only 15 elements. So S=15. Based on your statement, O(2^n) = 2^15 (figure a has 15 nodes. Recall n means number of nodes) which comes up to 32767.So your S vector size() = 32767 instead of 15. The max is only 15. There's where my confusion is. Same apply for your degenerated tree.

Comment: Figure a: h=3 (according to Wikipedia), S = 16 (including index 0). O(2^n) is indeed 2^15, but that is a *worst* case, and figure a is not a worst case, since there the tree is balanced and all slots in S correspond to nodes. You are saying that S is always equal to *n*, but that is not the case. *n* is about the number of *real* nodes in the tree, while S is about the size of the vector. The two are different metrics. S can be a lot greater than *n* when the tree is not balanced.

Comment: Look at the example I gave, which **is** a worst case. There n=4 and S=16. You can create a worst case for n=5, such that S=32. The best case for n=5 would be a balanced tree of height 2, and then S only needs to be 8. So for n=5, S could vary between 8, 16 or 32... it depends on the shape of the tree.

Comment: Let me digest. Really appreciate your help. I need to take sometime to digest your explanation.

Comment: Extended my answer a bit with the above comments elaborated.

Comment: Think i got it! Appreciate.